# Ghostscript - virtual printer output is only A4

Tags: printing, ghostscript, virtual-printer

I'm using ghostscript for Virtual Printer and I installed it according to this manual: http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~henrik/GSPSprinter/GSPSprinter.html

The problem is, that it prints everything in A4 no matter how big document is. (or what I set in dialog box). I need to print documents from MS Word sometimes in A3 and sometimes in A4, so I didn't set the default paper size.

**My setting right now is like this:**

```
-Ic:\gs\gs8.14\lib;c:\gs\fonts 
-sDEVICE=mswinpr2 
-dNoCancel 
-dNOPAUSE 
-dSAFER
```

I tried it with

```
-sPAPERSIZE=A4
```

and

```
-sPAPERSIZE=A4 
-sPAPERSIZE=A3
```

but didn't get any positive result.

Do you have any idea how to set it?

Thanks, Laura

Comment: Why are you doing this ? Why don't you print directly to the printer ? The normal use for mswinpr2 is to print existing PCL/PS/PDF to a printer which doesn't handle that type of input. But since you are printing from Word, why not just print straight to the printer ? Assuming you do have a good reason, the first thing you need to do is capture the PostScript being generated and sent to Ghostscript, and then post that somewhere public, and supply a URL here. Finally post a *full* GS command line (the one above cannot be complete) and tell us the printer you are using.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I can't print directly to the printer because I use the Win 7 64bit and the drivers for supporting this system doesn't exist. This is the only option how to make the printer work.

Comment: But the mswinpr2 device can only print to Windows printers that exist on the Windows system. It works by creating a Windows Device Context suitable for the printer, rendering a bitmap to that Device Context, and then telling Windows to print the Device Context. Unless I'm mistaken (and I don't believe I am), it cannot print to a printer that Windows has no drivers for. You can print to non-Windows pritners, if Ghostscript has a suitable device available, but not using mswinpr2.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
-sPAPERSIZE=a4 
-sPAPERSIZE=a3
```

(a instead of A)